# Submit a login form with out clicking the login button

Tags: javascript, dom

So I have a login.jsp where I have hard coded the username and password values.  My issue is I want the login to automatically submit the username and password values withhout  a user having to physically click login. So the login in screen will pretty much only be visible for a split second before the user is redirected to the next page.

```
    <div class="center-me">
<form:form name="login" id="login">

<div class="login_header_logo">
    <img border="0" src="<c:url value='img/pidslogo.gif' />" />
</div>

<div id="login_header">
    <h1>Login</h1>
</div><!-- #login_header -->

<div id="login_content">

    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="validationErrors" />    

    <table id="form_fields">
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            Username:
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <form:input path="username" cssClass="inputField" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="label">
            Password:
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <form:password path="password"cssClass="inputField" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr <c:if test="${repoListSize <= 1}">class="repository" style="display:none" </c:if>>
        <td class="label">
            Repository:
        </td>
        <td class="field">
            <form:select id="repository" path="repository" multiple="false">
                <c:forEach items="${repoList}" var="item">
                    <form:option value="${item.valueField}">${item.labelField}  </form:option>
                </c:forEach>
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <div id="submit1">
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
    </div> 

</div><!-- #login_content -->

</form:form><!-- #login -->
</div>

<script language="javascript">
TSG.util.onPageReady(function() {
    if (parent.frames.length > 0)
    {
        parent.location = this.location;
    }
    if (window.opener)
    {
        window.opener.document.location=this.location;
        window.close();
    }
    document.login.username.focus();
    Nifty("div#login_header","top, big");
});

document.getElementById("username").value = "111111111";
document.getElementById("password").value = "111111111";




</script>
```

Comment: What is the point in there even being a login page then?

Comment: This is so a guest can have access to "Public" documents... but in order to have access to these public documents you have to retrieve them from a datbase management system which requires user authentication.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the following line at the end of the script section, to submit the login form automatically:

```
document.forms["login"].submit();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help it was something I tried originally but it doesn't work.  The coded user name and password are generated in the text boxes and if I remove the document.forms["login"] from the jsp and login it works fine. With the script in the jsp the login fails.